# Problem in the addition operation (Xamarin Forms, Firebase)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for help to solve this little problem.

I am trying to create a method to sum the results I get from a database in firebase,
but in the end the result I got is: 0.

```
       int sumaM;

        public async Task<int> SumOperation()
        {
            var data = (await Cconection.firebase
                .Child("Operation")
                .OnceAsync<Operation>())
                .Select(item => new Operation
                {
                    Result = item.Object.Result,
                    Market = item.Object.Market

                }).Where(a => a.Market == "Sp500");
            
            int total = 0;
            total = data.Sum(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Result));
            sumaM = total;
            return sumaM;
        }


        public async Task<decimal> PromedioX()
        {
            var funcion = new DOperation();
            Promedio = await funcion.SumOperation();
            return Promedio;
        }
```

```
  But I get a result of: 0
```

[image: Result]

and this happens to me with more operations I try to do using Linq
thank you for your help

Comment: what are the values in `Result`?  Stock market prices are rarely modeled as integer values

Comment: ... and given that PromedioX returns `decimal`, presumably everywhere you have type `int`, you should instead have `decimal`.

Comment: The problem was the same, it had values (Int, decimal in the operation). thank you <3